# Verified if a point is inside a surface matlab

Tags: matlab, scatter

I have a surface interpolating 3D points  and  I would like to test whether a point is inside or outside this surface.
I know the 3D coordinates of the point and the 3D coordinates of its nearest point on the surface.

For example:

```
scatter3(1.715710000000000e+02 ,-1.389280000000000e+02, -1.395990000000000e+02,'*','r') % point
hold on
scatter3(1.692480000000000e+02,-1.355325000000000e+02 ,-1.395429000000000e+02,'filled','y') % nearest surface point 
hold on
```

or :

```
scatter3(1.780790000000000e+02, -1.505310000000000e+02, -1.481070000000000e+02,'*','r') % point
hold on
scatter3(1.795721000000000e+02,-1.346832000000000e+02, -1.499843000000000e+02,'filled','y') % nearest surface point
```

Plotting these points with surface, both these points seem to be within of the surface...
How can I prove it?

Thanks!

Comment: I would add that point to the scatter data and try to interpolate with the same surface again. Then I would check the resulted error. If adding a point enhances the error, it do not probably belong to that surface.

Comment: Without you specifying the data structure of your surface this question can't be answered. Please elaborate!

Comment: the surface consists of polygons interpolating cloud points and it is obtained as follows: surface=patch('Faces',poligoni,'Vertices',vertici);

Comment: When you mean "inside" the surface, what do you mean? Is the surface "closed", like an sphere? or you mean one side or the other of the surface? Or you just want to know if the point belongs to the surface?

Comment: Sorry! I mean a closed surface  similar to a rugby ball but it isn't a "regular solid"..

Comment: @rachi: If the surface is convex, you can simply use a `delaunayTriangulation` to construct the volume enclosed by the surface and then use the built-in function `pointLocation`. Also: Please add the information of your comment about the format of the data to the question instead!